# Python unit test coverage for multiple modules

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, python-unittest, coverage.py

I searched for a long time and surprisingly found no satisfactory answer.

I have multiple modules/files in my Python project that I wrote unit tests for using `unittest`. The structure is such that I have production-modules `module_A.py` and `module_B.py` in one directory (say `myproject/production`) and corresponding test-files `test_module_A.py` and `test_module_B.py` in a sibling directory (say `myproject/tests`).

Now I have `coverage.py` installed and want to run all the tests associated with the project (i.e. all `.py`-files with the prefix `test_` from the `tests` directory) and receive a coverage report showing the coverage for all the production-modules (`module_A.py` and `module_B.py`).

I figured out that I can do this by running the following commands from the `myproject/tests` directory:

- `coverage erase`
- `coverage run -a --source myproject.production test_module_A.py`
- `coverage run -a --source myproject.production test_module_B.py`
- `coverage report`

This gives me that nice table with all my production modules listed and their coverage results. So far so good.

**But can I do this with just one command?** Assuming I have not 2 but 20 or 200 tests that I want to include in one report, doing this "by hand" seems ridiculous.

There must be a way to automate this, but I can't seem to find it. Sure a shell-script might do it, but that is rather clumsy. I am thinking of something akin to `unittest discover`, but for `coverage.py` this doesn't seem to work.

Or could I accomplish this using the coverage-API somehow? So far I had no luck trying.

.

**SOLUTION:** (credit to Mr. Ned Batchelder)

From `myproject/tests` directory run:

`coverage run --source myproject.production -m unittest discover && coverage report`

One line, doing exactly what was needed.

Comment: Do you know nose2, could be a try. https://github.com/nose-devs/nose2

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This should do it:

```
coverage.py run -m unittest discover
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I knew I was just missing something about your package. Thanks! The full solution for me was `coverage run --source myproject.production -m unittest discover && coverage report`. Worked like a charm.